# Why won't my PHP loop work properly?

Tags: php

I am working on a social network project.

I have a table named `member` including information about each user: `name`, `age`, `gender`, and so on.

I am trying to display a default profile picture according to the user's gender.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT gender FROM member WHERE member_id = '$user_id'";
$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "gender is" . $row['gender'];
        if($row['gender'] ='female'){
?>

            <img src="..\img\female.png"  />

 <?php 
            break;
        }
        else if ($row['gender'] = 'male') {
 ?>
            <img src="..\img\male.png"  />

 <?php 
            break;
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

Now, the gender is being echoed out correctly, but it will always display a female's picture. What is it exactly that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make change in if statement,  equal sign is two times to equate

```
           <? php
            if($row['gender'] =='female'){
            ?>

               <img src="..\img\female.png"  />

          <?php break;}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! You're a life-saver! :)

Comment: Its glad... All the best @DeenaOsman

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your if statements. `=` is to assign and `==` is to compare. Try the following code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT gender FROM member WHERE member_id = '$user_id'";
$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "gender is".$row['gender'];
        if($row['gender'] =='female'){
            echo '<img src="..\img\female.png"  />';
            break;
        }
        else if($row['gender'] == 'male'){
            echo '<img src="..\img\male.png"  />';
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`=` assigns right value to left variable. You're assigning value in if statement instead of comparing them. Your if statement should be

```
If($row["gender"]=="male"){
   // code
}
```

Comment: Please change it to, `if($row["gender"]=="male")`

Comment: Still not correct. variable names must start with `$`, so change `row` to `$row`

Comment: Man this app actually sucks and I hate typing